# Why doesn't strstr appear to be working in my C program?

Tags: c

The source code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
"I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
"Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
"Dancing with a Dork",
"From here to maternity",
"The girl from Iwo Jima",
};


void find_track(char search_for[]) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for)) {
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for:");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

When I use the program as follows:

> Search for:town

I would expect something like

> Track 1: 'Newark, Newark - a wonderful town'

Instead my program exits and does not print anything.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
```

leaves the newline used to send the input to the programme in the input buffer, so the string passed to `strstr` as second argument is in fact

```
"town\n"
```

and that is not a substring of any of the `tracks`, so no match is found and nothing printed.

Remove the newline from the buffer,

```
size_t n = strlen(search_for);
if (n > 0 && search_for[n-1] == '\n') {
    search_for[n-1] = 0;
}
```

to have it search for `"town"`.